# Host Header will cause Invalid Argument Error in Puppeteer

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I'm using puppeteer with these settings:

```
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
   Headless = true,
   ExecutablePath = ChromePath,
   IgnoreHTTPSErrors = true
});
```

and I'm adding a Host header to my page:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("Host", "stackoverflow.com");
await page.SetExtraHttpHeadersAsync(dic);
```

then I use this to navigate to the URL:

```
await page.GoToAsync("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060208/inno-setup-window-preview-in-taskbar", 30000);
```

But it will give me an `invalid argument` error.
Removing the Host header will solve the problem, but why is it not working with the host header, and how to solve this issue if the Host header is needed?

Comment: I believe that's chromium who doesn't allow you to set such header (since this header is kind of restricted in a sense that browser manages this header itself).

Comment: @Evk yeah I know its chromium, but how to avoid it?

Comment: I think it cannot be avoided, but don't have a proof for that. Why do you need to set Host header in the first place?

Comment: @Evk so if not in the first place then when to change it?

Comment: I mean browser sets this header automatically. This is what is called forbidden header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name. It is not intended to be changed by third party code (when you are using browser like you are doing now)

Comment: @Evk here are some tips for overriding the host header in the `before request` event. what do u think then? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154900

Comment: Reports are quite mixed under this issue. Some report they were able to modify this header from extension, others say they have to fallback to proxies or redirection.

Comment: h2 doesn't have a host header. it has :authority:. Maybe you need to use a much older chromium.